# Optimizing try-except in API call

Tags: python, try-except

I have 2 functions that return the same result from API calls. Function1 is 1.5 times slower than function 2 and I can't figure why? I would also like to optimize the best one.

Function 1:

```
def get_pmid(df):
    pmid = []
    for doi in tqdm(df['DOI'].values):
        try:
            if convert.doi2pmid(doi) not in ['AMBIGUOUS', 'NOT_FOUND;INVALID_JOURNAL']:
                pmid.append(convert.doi2pmid(doi))
            else:
                pmid.append(None)
        except:
            pmid.append(None)
        time.sleep(uniform(0.6, 1.2))
    return pmid
```

Function 2:

```
def get_pmid_2(df):
    pmid = []
    for doi in tqdm(df['DOI']):
        try:
            pmid.append(convert.doi2pmid(doi))
        except:
            pmid.append(None)   
        time.sleep(uniform(0.6, 1.2))
    for x, y in enumerate(pmid):
        if y in ['AMBIGUOUS', 'NOT_FOUND;INVALID_JOURNAL']:
            pmid[x] = None
    return pmid
```

Answer (score 3):

**Why is first function slower then second?**

- You call `convert.doi2pmid` two times instead of one at each iteration.
- It is a bad practice to use `except` without specifying exception you expect (not affecting on performance)

**How can you optimize this function?**

Second algorithm has linear time-complexity, so it is already well-designed.

Comment: The first function doesn't have nested loops. Not any that really matter (the implicit loop with `in` operating over two constant values is hardly a loop).

Comment: @Fedor Soldatkin yes of course I'm making the API call twice.

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: I have Nonetype and IndexErrors. How do I handle these when I don't know which error will be triggered at each call?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `convert.doi2pmid(doi)` is a relatively expensive call. Your first example computes it twice any time the result isn't one of the two excluded results. Compute it once, store it, then test and (if appropriate) `append` the stored value. A decent use case for the walrus operator, `:=`:

```
def get_pmid(df):
    pmid = []
    for doi in tqdm(df['DOI'].values):
        try:
            # Cache result in p as well as testing membership
            if (p := convert.doi2pmid(doi)) not in ('AMBIGUOUS', 'NOT_FOUND;INVALID_JOURNAL'):
                pmid.append(p)  # append cached result
            else:
                pmid.append(None)
        except Exception:  # Please don't use bare except blocks; ideally, you'd target even more finely
            pmid.append(None)
        time.sleep(uniform(0.6, 1.2))
    return pmid
```